# Twilio,what is the parent callsid and child callsid?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

1.Can anyone please tell me what is the difference b/w parentcallsid and childcallsid?
Can I use update method using parent callsid?

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The parent Call Sid is the identifier of the first call that is made as part of a call flow. This call could be one [generated from the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) or an incoming call. Whichever way it happens, this first call will need to retrieve TwiML from the webhook URL that you set for the phone number or the URL you used as part of the REST API call to generate the call. Any calls that are then generated from that [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml), by using [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) for example, will have their own Call Sid, and will be children of the original call.

Let me know if that helps at all.